# Barometer with two liquids of different densities

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Okay, so I understand the basic working principle of a Hg barometer: Take a container with Hg, then take a tube filled with Hg and invert it inside the Hg in the container. The Hg in the tube drops into the container till the pressure exerted by the weight of the Hg inside the tube equals the atmospheric pressure exerted on the surface of Hg in the container.

I undestand that. But my question is what would happen if I were to instead take a liquid of density more than that of Hg in the tube and then continue with the experiment? Will the atmospheric pressure on the surface of Hg be able to keep the liquid in the tube upto a certain height or will it all just sink into the container?

P.S: I understand that a liquid denser than Hg at room temperature is not possible, but, for the sake of the question, lets say that such a liquid exists.

Comment: "take a liquid of density more than that of Hg in the tube and then continue with the experiment" How would you continue? What exactly would you do with the super-dense liquid?

Comment: @PhilipWood Invert it inside the Hg container, just like in the Hg barometer, so instead of Hg in the tube there would be my super-dense liquid.

Answer (score 1):

The level of the denser liquid in the tube would fall further than the mercury fell, so the equilibrium height of the liquid would be less than that for the mercury.

If the bowl were full of the denser liquid (density $\rho_2$, say) we could simply equate pressures at the liquid level in the bowl, just as we do for mercury, arriving at
$$\text{Atmospheric pressure} =h_2\rho_2\ g$$
in which $h_2$ is the height difference between liquid levels in the tube and the bowl.

For mercury we had
$$\text{Atmospheric pressure} =h_{Hg}\ \rho_{Hg}\ g$$
So
$$\frac{h_2}{h_{Hg}}=\frac{\rho_{Hg}}{\rho_2}.$$

But you still have mercury in the bowl, left over from the previous experiment? If we assume that the open bottom end of the tube is in mercury (the denser liquid from the top of the tube having fallen to the bottom of the bowl) then, equating pressures at the bottom of the tube
$$\text{Atmospheric pressure} + h_B\ \rho_{Hg}\ g=h_T\ \rho_2\ g$$
in which $h_B$ is the height of mercury in the bowl above the bottom of the tube, and $h_T$ is the height of liquid in the tube above the bottom of the tube.

Provided that the bowl is shallow compared with the height of liquid in the tube, $h_B\ \rho_{Hg}\ g$ will be small and won't make much difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Okay, so will the level remain same if instead of Hg in the container I took water but the tube still contains Hg just like Barometer? Basically build a barometer but replace the Hg in the container with water; will Hg in thr tube rise to the same level?

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the stability of the column, unless the bottom of the tube is actually in contact with mercury in the bowl. The mercury level in the bowl needs to be just above the bottom of the tube. Then you can add as much water to the bowl as you like, and the same equation applies as before, modified for the different liquids, namely $$\text{Atmospheric pressure} + h_B\ \rho_{H_2O}\ g=h_T\ \rho_{Hg}\ g$$
in which $h_B$ is the height of water in the bowl above the bottom of the tube, and $h_T$ is the height of mercury in the tube above the bottom of the tube.

Comment: Yeah but what if there is no mercury in the bowl just water? Also will the height of mercury in the tube increase if I immersed it deeper into the bowl with mercury(no water, just mercury in this case)?

Comment: (a) "but what if there is no mercury in the bowl just water?" I'm not sure that the mercury would stay in the tube; instabilities might arise across the bore of the tube. You'd probably be alright if the tube were very narrow. In which case you could use the equation I gave in my previous comment. (b) "will the height of mercury in the tube increase if I immersed it deeper into the bowl with mercury" Yes. The same equation applies as before, but this time the liquid on both sides of the equation is mercury. It's easy to work all this out by equating pressures at the same level in the Hg.

Answer (score -1):

You need not have Hg in your container, the pressure on water would be the same and the Hg still rises to its former level. You need the Hg in the container for varying pressure, so if pressure rises you still have Hg to go in the tube. Same with your material of higher density.

Comment: This is very difficult to parse.